# Running stored command with environment variables

Tags: sh

This works in `sh`:

```
$ export command="true"
$ "$command"
```

If I need to pass some variable to the command, however, I can't get it to work:

```
$ export command="env FOO=\"bar\" true"
$ "$command"
sh: 2: env FOO="bar" true: not found
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've put `$command` in quotes this prevents the shell from performing field splitting on it's contents, it's treated as one single word. Thus the name of the of command it tries to run is the full contents of `$command` including it's spaces and double quote characters.

You could omit the quotes and this almost does what you want:

```
export command="env FOO=\"bar\" true"
$command
```

Except this will set `FOO` to `"bar"` (with the double quotes) and not `bar` (without the quotes) as you probably expected. It also won't work if you try to set `FOO` to something with a space in it:

```
$ command="env FOO=\"bar foo\" true"
$ $command
env: foo": No such file or directory
```

The problem here being that double quote characters in the variable `command` are treated like any other character after being substituted. They aren't removed nor do they prevent field splitting.

What you can do instead is use the `eval` command:

```
command="env FOO=\"bar foo\" true"
eval "$command"
```

This causes the shell to completely re-evaluate everything after `eval` again and execute as a command. In other words after it does substitution, splitting, expansion, and quote removal on `eval "$command"` it then does substitution, splitting and expansion and quote removal on `env FOO="bar foo" true` as if it were the command entered into the shell.

However the `eval` command is very dangerous. You have to trust everything you pass to it. If you pass something that came from an untrusted user than the user can craft a string that will let him run any command he wants.

As an alternative to `eval` you can use either `alias` or a function. The `alias` command is just as dangerous as `eval`, but if you're only going to be using `$command` in from the command prompt and never from scripts then using an alias is the easiest and simplest solution:

```
$ alias mycommand="env FOO=\"bar\" true"
$ mycommand
```

If you're using it in shell scripts or both from the command line and in shell scripts I would use a function:

```
myfunc() {
    env FOO="bar" true
}
myfunc
```

As an aside you don't actually need to use `env` to set an environment variable for a command when using one of the Bourne shells, you can just set the variable:

```
FOO="bar" true
```

When used like this the variable assignment works like with the `env` command, it doesn't change the value of `FOO` in the shell's environment, only in the `true` command's environment.

Comment: Thank you for a very complete answer.